# Can I prevent a "You lose the game" event by countering the ability that creates it?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I cast [Chance for Glory](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bChance%20for%20Glory%5d), can I use [Stifle](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bStifle%5d), [Tale's End](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTale%27s%5d%2b%5bEnd%5d), [Disallow](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDisallow%5d), or [Voidslime](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bVoidslime%5d) to counter the game loss at the end of said extra turn?

Answer (score 4):

Chance for Glory's "At the beginning of that turn's end step, you lose the game" ability is a delayed trigger, so anything that counters triggered abilities will stop it. Hence yes, all four of the cards you mentioned will stop the game loss.

Comment: Also a good use for Sundial of the Infinite.